# Animation does not seem to work - move view from one position to another on [self dismissViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewanimation

I have a view currently on the screen and I would like to move it off the screen during an animation. Its current position is: `CGRectMake(0, 168, 320, 50);` and I would like to move it to y postion 218.

Here is my code:

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
 self.optionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 218, 320, 50);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Thanks in advance. Nothing is happening, the view isnt moving off screen.

Edit: When the app launches the view is off screen, i then call:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
 self.optionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 168, 320, 50);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

to bring the view into the main view. The problem I have is making the view go back off screen again with:

```
 [UIView beginAnimations:Nil context:NULL];
 [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
 self.optionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 218, 320, 50);
 [UIView commitAnimations];
```

It must be noted that in order to get the view to be off screen on app launch I call:

```
-(void) viewDidLayoutSubviews{
    self.optionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 218, 320, 50);
}
```

Update: I am also using the camera, i think dismissing the camera is affecting the layouts

Comment: what is the initial frame of optionsView?

Comment: @Nitesh 0,168,320,50, this is the original frame

Comment: Are you using Auto-layouts ?

Comment: @Basheer_CAD I am indeed, its iOS7

Comment: remove them and check again

Comment: Can you elaborate your edit? You may be using wrong `CGRect`.

Comment: @Desdenova please see the above edit

Comment: You've got 207 as the height in viewDidLayoutSubviews, is that intentional?

Comment: @GavinHope Sorry it was a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use block instead:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.view duration:0.3 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{

    // final view elements attributes goes here

} completion:nil];
```

This is the modern way of doing animations. You can even specify a completion block, something that should happed after the animation is done, if needed.

Comment: hmmmm, doesnt seem to work, but i can change the color of the view in this block so it must be something I am doing wrong

Comment: After toying around this was the best example. I had a minor bug in my code that was effecting it working completely. :)

Answer (score 3):

I've animated the position of views as follows:

```
// 'frame' variable previously declared
// 'completion' block previously declared

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     [_someView setFrame:frame];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished){
                     if (completion) {
                         completion();
                     }
                 }];
```

Have you tried it that way?

As Martin Koles has said, the block-based approach to view animation is preferred. The following is in the reference doc for `UIView`:

> Use of the methods in this section is discouraged in iOS 4 and later.
>   Use the block-based animation methods instead.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html

Comment: No problem. That quote above comes from the Tasks section in the UIView reference doc, where there are two sections of interest: (1) Animating Views and (2) Animating Views with Block Objects. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:0 options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear  
animations:^{
self.optionsView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 218, 320, 50);
} completion:nil];
```

Worked fine with me.
Make sure the view is connected in the xib to its proper object.

Comment: This should work I know but I doesnt seem to, please see above edit.

Comment: Have you created options view programmatically or through the nib? IF its via the nib make sure the view is connected to its proper outlet.

Comment: it is connecting in storyboard.